# Долгая разархивация ZipArchive

Tags: php

Использую `$zip = new ZipArchive();` Очень долго разархивирует маленький архив,  иногда по времени не успевает. В чем может быть причина или так и должно быть?
`Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Comment: а с архивом все в порядке? не пробовали другим архивом проверить?

Comment: маленький это сколько?

Comment: 160кб там много файлов мелких внутри

Comment: много это сколько? если несколько тысяч то мб и нормально, что долго делает

Comment: в 30 кб очень быстро берет,а 160 не успевает

Comment: так сколько файлов? может стоит структуру поменять поменять зип файла? например разбить по 100 файлов по подпапкам. Работает ли быстро с этим же зип файлов другие архиваторы?

Comment: так увеличьте лимиты времени на выполнение. не думаю, что вам удастся как то повлиять на скорость разархивации. и предсказать почему так долго невозможно. это зависит от вашего сервера и текущей нагрузки на него.