# Как копировать файл без загрузки на сервер?

Tags: php

Можно ли как то копировать файл не загружая его на сервер? Так как если на сервер, то 30 секунд не хватает. Когда делаю анзип то получаю ошибку `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Comment: Откуда копировать? Куда копировать? 30 секунд на что не хватает?

Comment: Есть архив на рабочем столе, я его копирую в какую то папку и там же анзип делаю, но  получаю ошибку `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` Я так понимаю загрузка на сервер идет и не успевает обработать, можно как то по другому сделать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733248/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ziparchive